# Bluetooth LE scan as non root?

Tags: non-root-user, bluetooth

To perform a scan for bluetooth LE devices *hcitool* apparently requires root privileges. For normal users the output is following:

```
$ hcitool lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Operation not permitted
```

Why does *hcitool* need root privileges for a LE scan?

Is it possible to somehow perform a LE scan as non-root?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Bluetooth protocol stack for Linux checks two capabilities. Capabilities are a not yet common system to manage some privileges. They could be handled by a PAM module or via extended file attributes. (see https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.10/source/net/bluetooth/hci_sock.c#L1307)

```
 $> sudo apt-get install libcap2-bin
```

installs linux capabilities manipulation tools.

```
 $> sudo setcap 'cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip' `which hcitool`
```

sets the missing capabilities on the executable quite like the setuid bit.

```
 $> getcap !$
 getcap `which hcitool`
 /usr/bin/hcitool = cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+eip
```

so we are good to go:

```
$>hcitool -i hci0 lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

Yeay, your BT adapter does not support BLE

```
$>hcitool -i hci1 lescan
LE Scan...
```

This one does, go on and press a button on your device.

Comment: Thanks four pointing out the missing capabilities. It also helped me to use bluetoothctl as non root user on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Stretch! but in my case I added the capability to /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.

Comment: How to do it via a PAM module?

Answer (score 11):

Ok, at least I partially discovered why *hcitool* requires root privileges for a LE scan but not for a normal scan. Partially means, that I located the system call which fails due to insufficient privileges when running the LE scan as a normal user.

The "Operation not permitted" error is generated by a *writev* system call, with the call stack locking as follows (all functions implemented in *hci.c*, see the bluez source code):

```
hci_le_set_scan_parameters -> hci_send_req -> hci_send_cmd -> writev
```

The normal scan ("hcitool scan") apparently does not need to send any requests to the controller, but uses a dedicated *ioctl* request, calling:

```
ioctl(dd, HCIINQUIRY, (unsigned long) buf);
```

It seems that write access to the bluetooth controller is restricted, but why and how can I deactivate that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this installed, but a well-written device subsystem usually has a group associated with it. Add a user to the group, and you can access the device (for instance `disk` group allows raw hard drive access). Just do `ls -l` in `/dev` to check this. If that's not the case and the device belongs to `root` group, you can change this by adjusting the `udev` rules that govern naming, permissions and actions on hardware at detection (don't ask me how).

This goes for direct device access that you probably need in this case. Normal functionality of bluetooth is usually handled through a daemon with its own configuration, groups, permissions and so on. Check your distribution documentation, the groups may vary slightly.