# Qt application bluetooth error

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, bluetooth

I am working on some `Qt` application, which communicates with `Bluetooth` hardware. Now, if I run this app as normal user:
`[user@workstation]: /mnt/projects/btProjectBuild/debug>$ ./btClient`
I get following warning/error:
`qt.bluetooth.bluez: Missing CAP_NET_ADMIN permission. Cannot determine whether a found address is of random or public type.`
However, If I run same app with `sudo` prefix (as root):
`[user@workstation]: /mnt/projects/btProjectBuild/debug>$ sudo ./btClient`
I do not get this warning/error. I am using `ArchLinux Linux workstation 4.12.8-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Aug 18 14:08:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Where do I configure `bluez` to get rid of this warning/error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from qt5 bluetooth library not from bluez directly and there is working solution, explained in "[Bluetooth LE scan as non root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96106/bluetooth-le-scan-as-non-root)".