# Why does "hcitool lescan" require privileged system calls, while "hcitool scan" does not?

Tags: bluetooth

An answer on [Bluetooth LE scan as non root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96106/bluetooth-le-scan-as-non-root) indicates that with `hcitool lescan` an "Operation not permitted" error is generated by a `writev` system call (in `hci.c`).

```
hci_le_set_scan_parameters -> hci_send_req -> hci_send_cmd -> writev
```

What's so special about a Bluetooth LE scan compared to a normal Bluetooth scan?

PS: It reminds me of Torvalds quote: *requiring root password for mundane things is “moronic”*. There must be a very good reason for this, I hope.